# recorderJS record/download audio buffer WEB AUDIO API

Tags: javascript, html, audio, audio-recording, web-audio-api

I want to record the audio output from a simple drum sequencer and export it for download as a wav file. I have a live link to my current attempt at this implementation [attempt](http://www.enemy.social/sequencer/www).

The sum output of the sequencer is routed to the variable `finalMixNode`
yet setting this as the input for the recorder.js doesn't work. I think it may be a problem with the audio context but I can't figure it out. I successfully created a oscillator and recorded its output but I can't extend this to the sequencer.

Here is the main js code in which I am trying to record the output. I'm hoping someone will see what I am missing.

```
//audio node variables
var context;
var convolver;
var compressor;
var masterGainNode;
var effectLevelNode;
var lowPassFilterNode;

var noteTime;
var startTime;
var lastDrawTime = -1;
var LOOP_LENGTH = 16;
var rhythmIndex = 0;
var timeoutId;
var testBuffer = null;

var currentKit = null;
var reverbImpulseResponse = null;

var tempo = 120;
var TEMPO_MAX = 200;
var TEMPO_MIN = 40;
var TEMPO_STEP = 4;

if (window.hasOwnProperty('AudioContext') &&     !window.hasOwnProperty('webkitAudioContext')) {
window.webkitAudioContext = AudioContext;
}

$(function() {
init();
toggleSelectedListener();
playPauseListener();
lowPassFilterListener();
reverbListener();
createLowPassFilterSliders();
initializeTempo();
changeTempoListener();
});

function createLowPassFilterSliders() {
$("#freq-slider").slider({
value: 1,
min: 0,
max: 1,
step: 0.01,
disabled: true,
slide: changeFrequency
});
$("#quality-slider").slider({
value: 0,
min: 0,
max: 1,
step: 0.01,
disabled: true,
slide: changeQuality
});
}

function lowPassFilterListener() {
$('#lpf').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass("active");
$(this).blur();
if ($(this).hasClass("btn-default")) {
  $(this).removeClass("btn-default");
  $(this).addClass("btn-warning");
  lowPassFilterNode.active = true;
  $("#freq-slider,#quality-slider").slider( "option", "disabled", false       );
  }
  else {
  $(this).addClass("btn-default");
  $(this).removeClass("btn-warning");
  lowPassFilterNode.active = false;
  $("#freq-slider,#quality-slider").slider( "option", "disabled", true   );
  }
  })
  }

  function reverbListener() {
  $("#reverb").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(this).blur();
  if ($(this).hasClass("btn-default")) {
  $(this).removeClass("btn-default");
  $(this).addClass("btn-warning");
  convolver.active = true;
  }
  else {
  $(this).addClass("btn-default");
  $(this).removeClass("btn-warning");
  convolver.active = false;
  }
  })
  }

function changeFrequency(event, ui) {
var minValue = 40;
var maxValue = context.sampleRate / 2;
var numberOfOctaves = Math.log(maxValue / minValue) / Math.LN2;
var multiplier = Math.pow(2, numberOfOctaves * (ui.value - 1.0));
lowPassFilterNode.frequency.value = maxValue * multiplier;
 }

function changeQuality(event, ui) {
//30 is the quality multiplier, for now. 
lowPassFilterNode.Q.value = ui.value * 30;
}

function playPauseListener() {
$('#play-pause').click(function() {
var $span = $(this).children("span");
if($span.hasClass('glyphicon-play')) {
  $span.removeClass('glyphicon-play');
  $span.addClass('glyphicon-pause');
  handlePlay();
} 
else {
  $span.addClass('glyphicon-play');
  $span.removeClass('glyphicon-pause');
  handleStop();
  }
 });
 }

 function toggleSelectedListener() {
 $('.pad').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("selected");
 });
 }

function init() {
initializeAudioNodes();
loadKits();
loadImpulseResponses();
}

function initializeAudioNodes() {
context = new webkitAudioContext();
var finalMixNode;
if (context.createDynamicsCompressor) {
  // Create a dynamics compressor to sweeten the overall mix.
  compressor = context.createDynamicsCompressor();
  compressor.connect(context.destination);
  finalMixNode = compressor;
   } else {
  // No compressor available in this implementation.
  finalMixNode = context.destination;
  }


 // Create master volume.
 // for now, the master volume is static, but in the future there will    be a slider
 masterGainNode = context.createGain();
 masterGainNode.gain.value = 0.7; // reduce overall volume to avoid    clipping
 masterGainNode.connect(finalMixNode);

 //connect all sounds to masterGainNode to play them

//don't need this for now, no wet dry mix for effects
// // Create effect volume.
// effectLevelNode = context.createGain();
// effectLevelNode.gain.value = 1.0; // effect level slider controls this
// effectLevelNode.connect(masterGainNode);

// Create convolver for effect
convolver = context.createConvolver();
convolver.active = false;
// convolver.connect(effectLevelNode);

//Create Low Pass Filter
lowPassFilterNode = context.createBiquadFilter();
//this is for backwards compatibility, the type used to be an integer
lowPassFilterNode.type = (typeof lowPassFilterNode.type === 'string') ?     'lowpass' : 0; // LOWPASS
//default value is max cutoff, or passing all frequencies
lowPassFilterNode.frequency.value = context.sampleRate / 2;
lowPassFilterNode.connect(masterGainNode);
lowPassFilterNode.active = false;
}

function loadKits() {
//name must be same as path
var kit = new Kit("TR808");
kit.load();

//TODO: figure out how to test if a kit is loaded
currentKit = kit;
}

function loadImpulseResponses() {
reverbImpulseResponse = new ImpulseResponse("sounds/impulse-  responses/matrix-reverb2.wav");
 reverbImpulseResponse.load();
}


//TODO delete this
function loadTestBuffer() {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/102/102130_1721044-lq.mp3";
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

request.onload = function() {
context.decodeAudioData(
  request.response,
  function(buffer) { 
    testBuffer = buffer;
  },
  function(buffer) {
    console.log("Error decoding drum samples!");
  }
);
}
request.send();
}

//TODO delete this
function sequencePads() {
$('.pad.selected').each(function() {
$('.pad').removeClass("selected");
$(this).addClass("selected");
});
}

function playNote(buffer, noteTime) {
var voice = context.createBufferSource();
voice.buffer = buffer;

var currentLastNode = masterGainNode;
if (lowPassFilterNode.active) {
lowPassFilterNode.connect(currentLastNode);
currentLastNode = lowPassFilterNode;
}
if (convolver.active) {
convolver.buffer = reverbImpulseResponse.buffer;
convolver.connect(currentLastNode);
currentLastNode = convolver;
}

voice.connect(currentLastNode);
voice.start(noteTime);
}

function schedule() {
var currentTime = context.currentTime;

// The sequence starts at startTime, so normalize currentTime so that it's 0 at the start of the sequence.
currentTime -= startTime;

while (noteTime < currentTime + 0.200) {
  var contextPlayTime = noteTime + startTime;
  var $currentPads = $(".column_" + rhythmIndex);
  $currentPads.each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
      var instrumentName = $(this).parents().data("instrument");
      switch (instrumentName) {
      case "kick":
        playNote(currentKit.kickBuffer, contextPlayTime);
        break;
      case "snare":
        playNote(currentKit.snareBuffer, contextPlayTime);
        break;
      case "hihat":
        playNote(currentKit.hihatBuffer, contextPlayTime);
        break;
      case "tomhi":
        playNote(currentKit.tomhiBuffer, contextPlayTime);
        break;
      case "tommid":
        playNote(currentKit.tommidBuffer, contextPlayTime);
        break;  
      case "tomlow":
        playNote(currentKit.tomlowBuffer, contextPlayTime);
        break;  
      case "cl":
        playNote(currentKit.clBuffer, contextPlayTime);
        break; 
      case "cb":
        playNote(currentKit.cbBuffer, contextPlayTime);
        break;  
     case "cp":
        playNote(currentKit.cpBuffer, contextPlayTime);
        break;  
    case "cy":
        playNote(currentKit.cyBuffer, contextPlayTime);
        break;
    case "rs":
        playNote(currentKit.rsBuffer, contextPlayTime);
        break;  

    }
      //play the buffer
      //store a data element in the row that tells you what instrument
    }
  });
  if (noteTime != lastDrawTime) {
      lastDrawTime = noteTime;
      drawPlayhead(rhythmIndex);
  }
  advanceNote();
  }

  timeoutId = requestAnimationFrame(schedule)
  }

  function drawPlayhead(xindex) {
  var lastIndex = (xindex + LOOP_LENGTH - 1) % LOOP_LENGTH;

  //can change this to class selector to select a column
  var $newRows = $('.column_' + xindex);
  var $oldRows = $('.column_' + lastIndex);

  $newRows.addClass("playing");
  $oldRows.removeClass("playing");
  }

  function advanceNote() {
  // Advance time by a 16th note...
  // var secondsPerBeat = 60.0 / theBeat.tempo;
 //TODO CHANGE TEMPO HERE, convert to float
 tempo = Number($("#tempo-input").val());
 var secondsPerBeat = 60.0 / tempo;
 rhythmIndex++;
 if (rhythmIndex == LOOP_LENGTH) {
     rhythmIndex = 0;
 }

//0.25 because each square is a 16th note
noteTime += 0.25 * secondsPerBeat
// if (rhythmIndex % 2) {
//     noteTime += (0.25 + kMaxSwing * theBeat.swingFactor) * secondsPerBeat;
// } else {
//     noteTime += (0.25 - kMaxSwing * theBeat.swingFactor) * secondsPerBeat;
// }

}

function handlePlay(event) {
rhythmIndex = 0;
noteTime = 0.0;
startTime = context.currentTime + 0.005;
schedule();
}

function handleStop(event) {
cancelAnimationFrame(timeoutId);
$(".pad").removeClass("playing");
}

function initializeTempo() {
$("#tempo-input").val(tempo);
}

function changeTempoListener() {
$("#increase-tempo").click(function() {
if (tempo < TEMPO_MAX) {
  tempo += TEMPO_STEP;
  $("#tempo-input").val(tempo);
}
});

$("#decrease-tempo").click(function() {
if (tempo > TEMPO_MIN) {
  tempo -= TEMPO_STEP;
  $("#tempo-input").val(tempo);
} 
});
}



function __log(e, data) {
log.innerHTML += "\n" + e + " " + (data || '');
 }

 var audio_context;
 var recorder;

 function startUserMedia() {
 var input = finalMixNode;
 __log('Media stream created.');
 input.start();
 __log('Input connected to audio context destination.');

 recorder = new Recorder(input);
 __log('Recorder initialised.');
 }

 function startRecording(button) {
 recorder && recorder.record();
 button.disabled = true;
 button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
 __log('Recording...');
 } 

  function stopRecording(button) {
  recorder && recorder.stop();
  button.disabled = true;
  button.previousElementSibling.disabled = false;
  __log('Stopped recording.');

  // create WAV download link using audio data blob
  createDownloadLink();

recorder.clear();
 }

 function createDownloadLink() {
 recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var au = document.createElement('audio');
  var hf = document.createElement('a');

  au.controls = true;
  au.src = url;
  hf.href = url;
  hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
  hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
  li.appendChild(au);
  li.appendChild(hf);
  recordingslist.appendChild(li);
});
}

window.onload = function init() {
try {
  // webkit shim
 window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext ||   window.webkitAudioContext;
  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

 // audio_context = new AudioContext;
  __log('Audio context set up.');
} catch (e) {
  alert('No web audio support in this browser!');
}

startUserMedia();

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `finalMixNode` is scoped into the  `initializeAudioNodes()` function, therefore it is undefined when you call it from `startUserMedia()`.

Also, this variable is either a dynamicCompressor node or the AudioContext's destination.
Recorderjs needs a node with an output (which AudioDestinationNode doesn't have *currently*<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835768/recorderjs-record-download-audio-buffer-web-audio-api/30836305?noredirect=1#comment49726642_30836305)</sup> ) so make sure to construct your recorder with the final compressor node (or a final gainNode)

Executing this in my js console from your page does work :
`var recorder = new Recorder(compressor);`

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks @padenot for noticing me it's being discussed [here](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/349)</sub>

Comment: Note that the AudioDestinationNode might very well have an output in the future, so that i's more flexible.

Comment: @padenot well noted, thanks. Do you have specs' draft about it ?